# How to convert a VirtualBox image to be used by KVM?

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization

I have images (for Kubuntu 17.10 and Kubuntu 18.04) created in VirtualBox 5.2.4 in Kubuntu 16.04.

I now have qemu/kvm and would like to migrate the latest snapshots so that I can use them with kvm instead of VirtualBox.

The contents of `VirtualBox VMs` is as below:

```
~/VirtualBox VMs $ ls -lRh
.:
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x 4 dkb dkb 4.0K Feb 15 09:15 k1710
drwxrwxr-x 4 dkb dkb 4.0K Feb 16 16:26 KuBio

./k1710:
total 7.4G
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb  29K Feb 15 09:15 k1710.vbox
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb  29K Feb 15 07:48 k1710.vbox-prev
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 7.4G Nov 12 21:44 k1710.vdi
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 512K Dec 22 16:11 k1710.webm
drwx------ 2 dkb dkb 4.0K Feb 15 07:48 Logs
drwx------ 2 dkb dkb 4.0K Feb 14 15:30 Snapshots
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dkb dkb 591K Nov 13 17:59 VirtualBox_k1710_13_11_2017_17_59_21.png

./k1710/Logs:
total 524K
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 129K Feb 15 09:15 VBox.log
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 125K Feb 14 15:37 VBox.log.1
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 119K Feb 10 14:54 VBox.log.2
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 144K Feb  7 15:38 VBox.log.3

./k1710/Snapshots:
total 20G
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 7.7G Feb 15 09:15 {073d6252-0ebc-40ed-a7a4-0350f64bf5c9}.vdi
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 111M Nov 12 22:08 {106c9b18-fc15-4a6f-8454-bf976f048aff}.vdi
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 442M Nov 12 21:44 2017-11-12T16-14-07-530247000Z.sav
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 741M Nov 12 22:07 2017-11-12T16-37-27-474214000Z.sav
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 470M Nov 12 22:13 2017-11-12T16-42-58-030079000Z.sav
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 1.3G Dec 20 13:55 2017-12-20T08-25-18-814327000Z.sav
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 1.8G Nov 12 22:07 {608ba6f3-1847-46b9-ac88-adb3b58a3c65}.vdi
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 7.7G Dec 20 13:55 {6db7d3e3-f467-4bd0-b020-3203298fcf9f}.vdi
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb  50M Nov 12 22:12 {d0dd2a49-7d20-45f2-bef8-0bc739912628}.vdi

./KuBio:
total 6.5G
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb  15K Feb 16 16:26 KuBio.vbox
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb  16K Feb 16 16:26 KuBio.vbox-prev
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 6.5G Dec 21 16:41 KuBio.vdi
drwx------ 2 dkb dkb 4.0K Feb 16 15:53 Logs
drwx------ 2 dkb dkb 4.0K Feb 13 14:57 Snapshots

./KuBio/Logs:
total 536K
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 139K Feb 16 16:26 VBox.log
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 134K Feb 15 06:57 VBox.log.1
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 125K Feb 14 22:06 VBox.log.2
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 129K Feb 14 15:30 VBox.log.3

./KuBio/Snapshots:
total 27G
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb  11G Feb 16 16:26 {17329940-1c49-490a-9ea1-50497ecdb47c}.vdi
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 863M Dec 21 16:41 2017-12-21T11-11-07-932099000Z.sav
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 459M Dec 21 17:47 2017-12-21T12-17-09-222784000Z.sav
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 1.3G Jan 16 17:25 2018-01-16T11-54-51-707036000Z.sav
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 8.8G Jan 16 17:24 {24b1c5bc-1877-424a-a57f-60b48b777e58}.vdi
-rw------- 1 dkb dkb 4.9G Dec 21 17:47 {e3c4ee49-0990-4e67-91a3-5c9bf3c1659f}.vdi
~/VirtualBox VMs $
```

Comment: I found [this](https://www.randomhacks.co.uk/how-to-convert-virtualbox-vdi-to-kvm-qcow2/) but cannot test it

Comment: There is also `qemu-img`  which can be used like `qemu-img convert -f vdi -O raw old_vbox.vdi new_kvm.img`

Comment: I think you need to get rid of all the snapshots before you can convert the image.